# React app in vercel with Laravel as REST Api and Sanctum for authentication return unauthenticated in production

Tags: reactjs, laravel, rest, vercel, laravel-sanctum

Please help on this ,very sorry since i know there are many similar question like this but already tried many of them. Okay i have a react app hosted in vercel with domain like
`my-app.vercel.app` and i also have a server that hosted laravel application that use for rest api. my backend have real domain attached to. i am using sanctum as the authentication method for laravel. im using `api.php` for all my routes but it seems any request on route inside `middleware('auth:sanctum')` below

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/signout', [AuthController::class, 'signout']);
});
```

will return `unauthenticated`, i already tried many ways inlucing

set SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=my-app.vercel.app,*.vercel.app

set SESSION_DOMAIN=my-app.vercel.app

already send the `Bearer token` in `Authorization` headers for request.

already modified the `cors.php` file many times

already uncomment code in `http/kernel.php`

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
```

additional question, do i need to specify the port too since i deploy app on vercel so i dont have the port in url.